# Using statement without curly braces

Tags: c#

I'm looking at the Npgsql getting started examples and having a hard time understanding the use of the using statement.

```
var connString = "Host=myserver;Username=mylogin;Password=mypass;Database=mydatabase";

await using var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connString);
await conn.OpenAsync();

// Insert some data
await using (var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("INSERT INTO data (some_field) VALUES (@p)", conn))
{
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("p", "Hello world");
 await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
}
```

Why would one add "using" to the declaration of conn variable?

```
await using var conn = new NpgslConnection(connString);
```

Also, as there is no curly braces, why is conn not disposed before it is being used when inserting data in the following line?

```
await using (var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("INSERT INTO data (some_field) VALUES (@p)", conn))
```

When will it be disposed?

Comment: `conn` will consume a connection to the database, why wouldn't you `using` it.

Comment: Answering this would be pretty much the same as: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement 

and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using

Last question. A: *defines a scope at the end of which an object will be disposed.*

Comment: from Joel's link "Beginning with C# 8.0, you can use the following alternative syntax for the using statement that doesn't require braces..."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

using adding for guarantee what your connection will be close after transaction

```
await using var conn = new NpgslConnection(connString);
```

**On your last question.**

With the new C# 8 using declaration, the code with the using statement can be simplified. Curly brackets are no longer needed. At the end of the scope of the variable r (which is here the end of the method), the Dispose method is invoked. Here, the compiler also creates a *try/finally block to make sure Dispose is called if errors occur.